# rewriting XML to a sorted date version

Tags: c#, xml

I want to be able to write a program in C# that rewrites a XML file so that the Dates becomes sorted. Is there a way to do this?
I know how to read the XML file, but how do I make the program rewrite it so that the dates become sorted?

Here is the XML:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="transform.xslt"?>
<Root>
  <Customers>
    <Customer CustomerID="GREAL">
      <CompanyName>Great Lakes Food Market</CompanyName>
      <ContactName>Howard Snyder</ContactName>
      <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle>
      <Phone>(503) 555-7555</Phone>
      <FullAddress>
        <Address>2732 Baker Blvd.</Address>
        <City>Eugene</City>
        <Region>OR</Region>
        <PostalCode>97403</PostalCode>
        <Country>USA</Country>
      </FullAddress>
    </Customer>
    <Customer CustomerID="HUNGC">
      <CompanyName>Hungry Coyote Import Store</CompanyName>
      <ContactName>Yoshi Latimer</ContactName>
      <ContactTitle>Sales Representative</ContactTitle>
      <Phone>(503) 555-6874</Phone>
      <Fax>(503) 555-2376</Fax>
      <FullAddress>
        <Address>City Center Plaza 516 Main St.</Address>
        <City>Elgin</City>
        <Region>OR</Region>
        <PostalCode>97827</PostalCode>
        <Country>USA</Country>
      </FullAddress>
    </Customer>
    <Customer CustomerID="LAZYK">
      <CompanyName>Lazy K Kountry Store</CompanyName>
      <ContactName>John Steel</ContactName>
      <ContactTitle>Marketing Manager</ContactTitle>
      <Phone>(509) 555-7969</Phone>
      <Fax>(509) 555-6221</Fax>
      <FullAddress>
        <Address>12 Orchestra Terrace</Address>
        <City>Walla Walla</City>
        <Region>WA</Region>
        <PostalCode>99362</PostalCode>
        <Country>USA</Country>
      </FullAddress>
    </Customer>
    <Customer CustomerID="LETSS">
      <CompanyName>Let's Stop N Shop</CompanyName>
      <ContactName>Jaime Yorres</ContactName>
      <ContactTitle>Owner</ContactTitle>
      <Phone>(415) 555-5938</Phone>
      <FullAddress>
        <Address>87 Polk St. Suite 5</Address>
        <City>San Francisco</City>
        <Region>CA</Region>
        <PostalCode>94117</PostalCode>
        <Country>USA</Country>
      </FullAddress>
    </Customer>
  </Customers>
  <Orders>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>6</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1997-05-06T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1997-05-20T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1997-05-09T00:00:00">
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
        <Freight>3.35</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>8</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1997-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1997-08-01T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1997-07-14T00:00:00">
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
        <Freight>4.42</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
    <Order>
      <CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>
      <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
      <OrderDate>1997-07-31T00:00:00</OrderDate>
      <RequiredDate>1997-08-28T00:00:00</RequiredDate>
      <ShipInfo ShippedDate="1997-08-05T00:00:00">
        <ShipVia>2</ShipVia>
        <Freight>116.53</Freight>
        <ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>
        <ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>
        <ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>
        <ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>
        <ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>
        <ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>
      </ShipInfo>
    </Order>
</Orders>
</Root>
```

I want it to get sorted by *OrderDate*

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument xDoc;
            xDoc = XDocument.Load("CustomerOrders.xml");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It partly depends on the structure of the XML, but it should be easy in LINQ to XML: a) load the XML; b) get the relevant elements (e.g. as a list) and order them with normal LINQ operations; c) replace the original set of elements with the ones in the right order, e.g. by removing them all and re-adding.

Comment: XML doesn't know about Dates.  It is a text file following a standard format.  The interpretation of the XML is often governed by a Schema, but not always.  Short answer is - since you can read it in, you can write your program to do anything you want, including rewrite the XML anyway you like.  But you will need to help us help you with a little more information.

Comment: One way would be to deserialize the XML to a list of objects (dates?), sort the list and serialize it back.

Comment: @JonSkeet How do I get the OrderDate and sort them?

Comment: Well what have you tried? There are *lots* of questions about finding child elements, and probably quite a few about converting an `XElement` into a `DateTime` (hint: you can cast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> myInts = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
            myInts.ForEach(x => x += 1);


            string input =
                "<Root>" +
                    "<Orders>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>8</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1997-07-04T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1997-08-01T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1997-07-14T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>2</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>4.42</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1997-07-31T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1997-08-28T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1997-08-05T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>2</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>116.53</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>3</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1997-09-25T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1997-10-23T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1997-09-30T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>3</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>76.13</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1998-01-06T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1998-02-03T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1998-02-04T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>2</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>719.78</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>3</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1998-04-07T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1998-05-05T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo ShippedDate=\"1998-04-15T00:00:00\">" +
                            "<ShipVia>2</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>25.19</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                        "<Order>" +
                          "<CustomerID>GREAL</CustomerID>" +
                          "<EmployeeID>4</EmployeeID>" +
                          "<OrderDate>1998-04-22T00:00:00</OrderDate>" +
                          "<RequiredDate>1998-05-20T00:00:00</RequiredDate>" +
                          "<ShipInfo>" +
                            "<ShipVia>3</ShipVia>" +
                            "<Freight>18.84</Freight>" +
                            "<ShipName>Great Lakes Food Market</ShipName>" +
                            "<ShipAddress>2732 Baker Blvd.</ShipAddress>" +
                            "<ShipCity>Eugene</ShipCity>" +
                            "<ShipRegion>OR</ShipRegion>" +
                            "<ShipPostalCode>97403</ShipPostalCode>" +
                            "<ShipCountry>USA</ShipCountry>" +
                          "</ShipInfo>" +
                        "</Order>" +
                    "</Orders>" +
                "</Root>";

            //read file
            XDocument root = XDocument.Parse(input);

            //sort orders by date
            var sortedOrder = root.Descendants("Order").OrderBy(x => (DateTime)x.Element("OrderDate")).ToList();

            //get order element from document
            XElement orders = root.Descendants("Orders").FirstOrDefault();
            //replace original Orders element with new element containing sorts orders
            orders.ReplaceWith(new XElement("Orders",sortedOrder));
            //save file
            root.Save("filename");



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use a XML-file instead of that input String??

Comment: Yes. XDocument root = XDocument.Load("filename");

Comment: Thanks. 
What if there are other elements than the "Orders"? Lets say there are "<Customer> after <root>. Is there a way to display it as well?

Comment: Try this : XElement orders = root.Descendants("Orders").FirstOrDefault();
            orders.ReplaceWith(new XElement("Orders",sortedOrder));
            root.Save("filename");

Comment: Can you update your solution? I updated my question and added new XML. I want the <customer> to display aswell

Comment: Commented code.  New code replaces the Orders so everything else in the XML will remain.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, try a serialise and deserialise combo. For example:

POCO classes:

```
public class XMLExample
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public List<XMLExample> XMLExamples { get; set; }
}
```

And the serialisation and deserialisation in one method:

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Just store this as a string for thie example
        string xml = "<Root><XMLExamples><XMLExample><Date>1997-10-23T00:00:00</Date></XMLExample><XMLExample><Date>2001-10-23T00:00:00</Date></XMLExample></XMLExamples></Root>";
        Root xmlData;
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

        // Deserialize to Root object
        using (var reader = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            object obj = deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
            xmlData = (Root)obj;
        }

        xmlData.XMLExamples = xmlData.XMLExamples.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();

        // Now Serialize the sorted object
        string sortedXml = string.Empty;

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, xmlData);

            sortedXml = writer.ToString();
        }

        Console.WriteLine(sortedXml);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To sort by OrderDate:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
// Get all the orders
var orders = root.Descendants("Order").ToList();
// Remove the orders from the XML file
orders.Remove();
// Sort the orders
var sortedOrders = orders.OrderBy(o => (DateTime)o.Element("OrderDate"));
// Re-Add them to the XML file
root.Element("Orders").Add(sortedOrders);
root.Save(file);
```

Comment: Does this override the file to become sorted?

Comment: Yes, it overrides the file with the sorted version. Or save it as a different file if you want to test it.

Comment: Apparently needed a `.ToList()` added to the getting of the Orders. Doesn't make sense to me, but there you go.